# ExoPlayer - How to assemble segments of downloaded DASH stream to a single MP4 file?

Tags: android, mp4, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

I am testing the new download manager feature of ExoPlayer with DASH streams.
After selecting a specific stream (e.g. 4mbps) to download, I found the following segmented files in ExoPlayer file folder.

```
   2389 Aug  1 16:51 0.0.1533113388415.v3.exo
   1015 Aug  1 16:51 1.0.1533113388538.v3.exo
2097152 Aug  1 16:51 1.1015.1533113388715.v3.exo
2097152 Aug  1 16:51 1.10530939.1533113395025.v3.exo
2097152 Aug  1 16:51 1.12628091.1533113396368.v3.exo
 179128 Aug  1 16:51 1.14725243.1533113397052.v3.exo
2097152 Aug  1 16:51 1.14904371.1533113397706.v3.exo
2097152 Aug  1 16:51 1.17001523.1533113399207.v3.exo
 318652 Aug  1 16:51 1.19098675.1533113399934.v3.exo
2097152 Aug  1 16:51 1.19417327.1533113400587.v3.exo
2097152 Aug  1 16:51 1.2098167.1533113390221.v3.exo
 256257 Aug  1 16:51 1.21514479.1533113402139.v3.exo
1362774 Aug  1 16:51 1.4195319.1533113391101.v3.exo
2097152 Aug  1 16:51 1.5558093.1533113392003.v3.exo
2097152 Aug  1 16:51 1.7655245.1533113393492.v3.exo
 778542 Aug  1 16:51 1.9752397.1533113394264.v3.exo
    147 Aug  1 16:51 cached_content_index.exi
```

Is there any way to assemble those into a single MP4 video file?

Comment: have you try this

Comment: @WaleedAsim which link are you referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java
@Robin